# webpack 2 exits with code 3221226505 when importing external css (in vue.js component)

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, vue.js, material-components

I'm trying to use [Google's Material Components for Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) in my project.
The problem is that when I'm adding the [import statement](https://github.com/sk22/spg-tinf-sem03/blob/e1f88f1eca510efa23f615abb0850ca0ca12565c/proj01/src/components/App.vue#L10), webpack doesn't output anything but exits with code `3221226505`, according to npm.

Here's a snippet of my App.vue:

```
import 'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css';
```

The project's commit tree can be found [here](https://github.com/sk22/spg-tinf-sem03/tree/e1f88f1eca510efa23f615abb0850ca0ca12565c/proj01), and [here](https://hastebin.com/lawecukata)'s the npm log in case it contains anything interesting.

I hope someone can help me with this issue. If you find anything else unconventional in my repo, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your webpack config

Comment: @LucasKatayama, I linked the whole repository. Aside from that, I already answered the question, which was much more trivial than I expected. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah ... I was thinking about the loader... That's why I asked for the config...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I just forgot to define a loader for css files. Even though I'm still wondering why webpack just exits with some error code...

However, here's a part of my updated `webpack.config.js`.
`module.exports.module.rules` does now contain this:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using to import css is wrong, it should be like following in your index.html as is given in the [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web#quick-start):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css">
```

But `node_modules` will not be accessible as you are using webpack, you can move this file to your static folder and import it like following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/material-components-web.css" type="text/css">
```

Following is complete code from [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web#quick-start):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="mdc-typography">
  <head>
    <title>Material Components for the web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/material-components-web.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    //HTML where you use material components
    <script src="/static/material-components-web.js"></script>
    <script>mdc.autoInit()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The guide doesn't assume you're using webpack. And in webpack, you should be able to import css inside javascript.

Comment: @22samuelk You can copy this `material-components-web.css` and put it in static folder, which can be used by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/material-components-web.css" type="text/css">`. I will update the answer.